# Programmatically change the FPS and/or Refresh Rate in Steam Deck

Tags: c++, steam, steamworks-api

I'm planning to build a plugin for Steam Deck that will programmatically change the refresh rate and/or FPS depending on several parameters on the deck. This should be able to change the FPS/Refresh rate on-demand without restarting the system.

This is already possible from the UI, which means there should be a way.

Is there any way to do this?

I looked in many places including the [official documentation](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/sdk/api) of the API and the [GitHub repos](https://github.com/ValveSoftware), but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Steam Deck is powered by SteamOS, which is purely Linux based, so you will need to use Linux commands to be able to change the FPS/Refresh rate.

With this, you can use `xrandr`, which is a command line tool for configuring displays with Linux systems. From there, you can preview the below links, all information is listed there.

Here is additional information:
https://github.com/sonic2kk/steamtinkerlaunch/wiki/Installation
https://github.com/ValveSoftware/gamescope